# VBA Shell no longer working in Windows 11

Tags: vba, windows, shell

I recently updated to Windows 11 and I notice that the Shell call does not longer open the Notepad.

It seems that Windows 11 now has notepad in the "C:\Windows" directory as well as the "C:\Windows\System32" directory but when I run this command using either, it no longer opens the notepad, it just runs and nothing happens

```
Dim x As Variant
x = Shell("C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe ""C:\test.txt""")
```

Is anyone else experiencing this behavior or found a way around it?

Comment: `Windows 11 now has` - [long, long before that](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060328-17/?p=31753).

Comment: Try adding `, vbNormalFocus` in your shell call just before the closing paren.

Comment: This worked, I guess in Windows 11 this is needed. vbNormalFocus, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding **vbNormalFocus** did the trick. Thank you David